# Find the center of a Circle tangent to two circles with a known radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

[image]

In this image, I need to find the center point of a tangent circle to two other circles with a known radius.

The information I can gather is:
$rT$,
$rA$,
$rB$,
$(Ax,Ay)$,
$(Bx,By)$,

Not given is:
$(TAx,TAy)$,
$(TBx,TBy)$,
$(Tx,Ty)$,

I searched for answers on this site, but couldn't find any before posting.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for $(Tx,Ty)$?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for (Tx,Ty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(T_x,T_y)$ is a distance of $rT+rA$ from the center of $A.$

and $rT+rB$ from the center of $B.$

Solve this system of equations:

$(x-A_x)^2 + (y-A_y)^2 = (rT + rA)^2\\
(x-B_x)^2 + (y-B_y)^2 = (rT + rB)^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, $T$ is $rT + rB$ from $B.$  (I had it correct in the algebra bellow.)

Comment: It is important to point out that the line between the centers of the circles goes through the tangent point.  That justifies the claim that the distance between the centers of $A$ and $T$ is $rA+rT$